# How to debug why "Linting and checking validity of types" step with Next.js is taking over 10 minutes?

Tags: next.js

I just added a single `.json` file with lots of nested data (~5MB), and dynamically imported that in `getServerSideProps`. I then fetch a nested value from that, type it, and render a page using that data, nothing too fancy.

But with that small change (too complicated to isolate for this question, as it's a full fledged Next.js project), the `info  - Linting and checking validity of types...` step on `npm run build` (and on Vercel) is taking over 20 minutes to run (and it's still "linting").

How can I get some insight into what change caused this explosion in build time (from previously < 1 min to build, to now > 20 minutes to build)? What is happening internally in `npm run build`, and can I log more details of what is being checked? Maybe there is something that is causing an infinite loop, or too complex of a type definition perhaps. Anything to help debugging would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The app itself runs fine under `npm run dev`.